# AWS Cloudwatch alarm set to NonBreaching (or notBreaching) is not triggering, based on a log filter

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

With the following Metric and Alarm combination

- Metric

  - Comes from a Cloudwatch log filter (when a match is found on the log)
  - Metric value: "1"
  - Default value: None
  - Unit: Count
- Alarm

  - Statistic: Sum
  - Period: 1 minute
  - Treat missing data as: notBreaching
  - Threshold: [Metric] > 0 for 1 datapoints within 1 minute

The alarm goes to:
State changed to **OK** at 2018/12/17.

**Reason**: Threshold Crossed: no datapoints were received for 1 period and 1 missing datapoint was treated as [NonBreaching].

And then it doesn't trigger, even though I force the metric > 0

Why is the alarm stuck in OK? How can the alarm become triggered again?

Comment: Ref: [Alarm doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Remove the "Unit" property from the stack template Alarm config.

The source of the problem was actually the "[Unit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-unit)" property. This being set to "Count" actually made the alarm become stuck :(

Ensure the stack is producing the same result as a manual alarm setup by checking with the [`describe-alarms`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html) API.